# I'm trying to display the Image after the lotti progress finished and disappeared but I couldn't in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

Here is my code:

```
    const Success =({navigation})=>{
     
    

  useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(()=>{

      <View>
        <Image  source={images.done}
          style={{
             width:100,
            height:100
      }}
      />
    </View>
    navigation.navigate('Home')

    },4000)
  }, [])

    
    return(
        <View style={{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
        }}>
    <LottieView
        style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 60,
        }}
        source={images.progress}
     autoPlay 
      />
        </View>
    )
}


export default Success ;
```

Please Help me out How I can display first Lotti progress and then immediately I wanna the image done appears after the Lotti progress finish and disappear. so I would know how to set time for Lotti progress and then set time to display the Image done then navigate to the next page

Comment: these time are based in what?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `onAnimationFinish` props in [lottie-react-native](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/blob/master/docs/api.md#component-api) library. Tell the program what you are going to do when the lottie animation end.

```
const Success = ({navigation}) => {

  const [lottieFinished, setLottieFinished] = useState(false);

  const onAnimationFinish = () => {
    setLottieFinished(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      //Go Back to home page after 4 seconds
      navigation.navigate('Home')
    }, 4000);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {
        !lottieFinished ?
          <LottieView
            source={images.progress}
            autoPlay
            loop={false}
            onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
          />
          :
          <Image
            source={images.done}
            style={{height:100, width:100}}
          />
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..... I really appreciate your help...it is working as I would like